# Indesign to JPG

Tags: jpeg, adobe-indesign

I need to save every page of a Indesign CS3 and Quark file as JPEG , in my cocoa application using Objective C...

can anyone suggest me on this?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a task for Applescript. You could write an applescript that uses the Indesign Applescript Dictionary and then wrap your applescript with Cocoa and Objective C.

[Indesign and Applescript](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.11/2211AppleScript/index.html)

[Cocoa to Applescript bridge](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Not sure how to do Cocoa wrapper around applescript? There are some code examples in the developer tools code samples that come with Xcode.

This might be useful [AppleScript and Cocoa: from Top to Bottom](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/applescriptforapps.html).

Answer (score 1):

Export PDF followed by export as JPEG.
To export as PDF take a look at this thread: http://objectmix.com/adobe-indesign/238509-newbie-question-how-batch-export-multiple-indd-pdf-files.html

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is really what you want but this InDesign JavaScript *might* help you somewhat. It exports each page of the open document to a separate jpeg.

```
var myFilePath, myFile,myDoc, myPages, myPage, myPageNum;

app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegQuality = JPEGOptionsQuality.high;
app.jpegExportPreferences.exportResolution = 200;
app.jpegExportPreferences.jpegExportRange = ExportRangeOrAllPages.EXPORT_RANGE;

myDoc = app.activeDocument;
myPages = myDoc.pages;
for (var i = 0; i < myPages.length; i++) {
    myPage = myPages[i];
    myPageNum = myPage.name;
    myFilePath = "~/Desktop/exported_jpegs/" + myDoc.name.replace(/indd$/, "") + " page " + myPageNum + ".jpg";
    myFile = new File(myFilePath);
    app.jpegExportPreferences.pageString = myPageNum;
    myDoc.exportFile(ExportFormat.jpg, myFile, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just File > Export, and then select Jpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Indesign (CS3) Applescript Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/products/indesign/scripting/pdfs/InDesignCS3_ScriptingGuide_AS.pdf) (pdf). It would have the details of what actions can be scripted.

Also, you might consider Automator which is essentially a GUI frontend to Applescript. Here some [Automator actions specifically for Indesign](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/automator/indesignautomatoractionpackforleopard.html).

And [a workflow guide from Adobe using Automator and Indesign](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/products/indesign/scripting/pdfs/indesign_automator_tutorial.pdf). It has some information on what to do in Xcode.